# Maximizing a form (JFrame) by default when it opens

Tags: java, swing

How can I Maximizing a form (`JFrame`) by default when it opens?I have tried the net but could not get an appropriate code by which it can be done.

Comment: Maximize it when you make it visible... Now I'm sure how to maximize a JFrame is in the internet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before making the frame visible and after pack() is called, call this -

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Assuming "this" is an instance of JFrame.

Comment: Thank a lot for your brief and accurate answer.